# how to get kestrel to listen on localhost:5001 on nginx

Tags: c#, nginx, https, raspberry-pi, kestrel

I have a .net api with an angular front end bundled in it.  It has been hosted on my raspberry pi for several weeks now with no issue using my domain with https certs and nginx proxies.  My proxies are pointed to https://localhost:5001 which dotnet had been listening on all along.  I recently updated it with new code and it no longer listens on 5001 with https.  This has resulted in a 502 bad gateway error in the console for all the calls angular makes to dotnet.
I did not change anything that I am aware of that would cause it to stop listening on 5001. The extent of the backend changes to dotnet were an extra DB table migration along with additional controller endpoints.
Why would it no longer listen on 5001?  What could I have possibly changed?

AppSettings only has some string values for constants.  no config.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers();
  services.AddSignalR();

  services
    .AddCors(options =>
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builderP => builderP
      .AllowAnyOrigin()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyHeader()))
      .AddHostedService<CommandHandler>()
      <several .addTransient IThing, Thing here>
      .AddSpaStaticFiles(options => { options.RootPath = "wwwroot"; });
}
```

In configure():

```
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseCors();
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseWebSockets(new WebSocketOptions
  {
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
  });

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapHub<MainHub>("/hubs/mainHub");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller}/{action=index}/{id?}");
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your kestrel configuration, otherwise its hard to help

Comment: @TheTanic added additional images.  launch settings are untouched.  What else would you need to see?

Comment: Please dont add code as images. The appsettings are missing. And the configureServices ist not fully visible

Comment: Apologies for that, updated with code blocks.  AppSettings has nothing but some custom string values im using for constants

Comment: Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configureiconfiguration This should help you

Comment: If it stopped working the certificate may of expired.  HTTPS uses TLS for obtaining an encryption key.  TLS is performed before the HTTP Request is sent.  So when TLS fails there is no connection which probably account for part of the error message/

Comment: That was it!  @jdweng I had to refresh the dev certs that had expired.  I used the link TheTanic provided and went with the dev tools link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-dev-certs
Ran the https command to refresh the cert and voila!   Thank you both!